# Can not get innerHTML from a jQuery Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I am using google map api.
I wrote the code below.

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

And I use the google chrome console to see the content of `$("div#map")`.

```
console.log($("div#map"));
```

The result is:

```
[
<div id=​"map" style=​"width:​ 1218.222222328186px;​ position:​ relative;​ background-color:​ rgb(229, 227, 223)​;​ overflow:​ hidden;​ -webkit-transform:​ translateZ(0)​;​ ">​
<div style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 0px;​ top:​ 0px;​ overflow:​ hidden;​ width:​ 100%;​ height:​ 100%;​ z-index:​ 0;​ ">​…​</div>​
</div>​
]
```

How can I get the innerHTML :

```
<div style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 0px;​ top:​ 0px;​ overflow:​ hidden;​ width:​ 100%;​ height:​ 100%;​ z-index:​ 0;​ ">​…​</div>​
```

I tried `$("div#map > div")`, but there is nothing returned.
Why? Is it because the innerHTML generated by Javascript?
How can I get it and insert another div into the div above?

Thank you very much.

Comment: $() returns an array with search results, even if there is only 1 element that matches. That is why the answers tell you to use $("#map")[0]

Answer (score 6):

To get a plain javascript dom object from a valid jquery selector, use `get(0)` or `[0]`.

```
$("#map")[0]//note that as id's are unique, you do not need to have anything else
            //in here to target them
```

Once you have the plain DOM object, you can use `innerHTML`

```
$("#map")[0].innerHTML
```

Although an easier way, since you are already using jQuery, would be to use jQuery's version of innerHTML `html`.

```
$("#map").html()
```

As for your second question, you can insert a div into the div like this:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = "simple text, probably want to make more elements and set attributes and build them using .appendChild().";
$("#map")[0].appendChild(newDiv);
```

Or like this for the parent of map:

```
$("#map")[0].parentNode.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.But there are nothing returned when using $("#map").html(). And I want to get the inner HTML $("#map")[0].child.child innerHTML. How can I get it?

Comment: @user1836330 - If there is nothing inside of `$("#map").html()` then it is possible the page or element is not loaded yet. If you want to get the innerHTML of a child of `$("#map")` then use [jQuery find](http://api.jquery.com/find/). `$("#map").find()`

Comment: I tried many times and changed the place of the code . But the result is still "". What I want to do is to add a custom control to google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager. I cant find a way to do this. Thank you very much!

Comment: when I refresh the page. The first time, the result of console.log($("div#map")[0]); is <div id=​"map" style=​"width:​ 1218.222222328186px;​ ">​</div>​ and then if I refresh again, the result becomes HTMLDivElement.

Comment: @user1836330 - Try surrounding your jquery in $(function(){ /* code here */ });

Answer (score 0):

Use the `html()` method to get the html from a jQuery object.

```
console.log($("div#map").html());
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: I tried console.log($("div#map").html()); But there are nothing returned.

Comment: @user1836330 - if you tried `console.log($("div#map").html());` and there was nothing, then perhaps you are calling it too soon before the map has been populated or you have an error that is keeping it from being executed.

Comment: I tried many times and changed the place of the code . But the result is still "". What I want to do is to add a custom control to google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager. I cant find a way to do this. Thank you very much!